# How should I use heterogeneous documents from a RavenDB Query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ravendb

When querying an index that returns heterogeneous documents, what is the best™ / most widely used / most widely accepted way of working with the result set?

An obvious answer is to load them as a common base type and then up-cast to more specific types, but this doesn't seem scalable.

A common scenario where I can see this being relevant is in search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely, you'll see that the results are *already* POCOs.  They are hydrated by the raven client based on their `Raven-Entity-Name` metadata.

You can use a common base type or interface, sure.  If you had lots of unrelated data, you could just use `object`.  Then later in your app you could filter them and cast them appropriately, or just use them as-is.

Try this as an experiment.  Store a few documents of three separate unrelated entity types and multimap them back.  Or go against any index that returns multiple different document types.  Heck, even `Raven/DocumentsByEntityName` that the studio builds should do it.  Query against this index like so:

```
var results = session.Query<object>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName");
```

*(With the usual, wait for non stale results, ToList, etc.)*

Set a breakpoint and look at the results you get back.  They are all indeed the correct types already, they are just different types depending on what document was returned.  Do what you want with them.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I've re-worded my question a little. I guess due to polymorphism, you're going to have to deal with them as a common base type or some kind of `if(resultItem is SomeClass)` and cast them appropriately. Would you agree.

Comment: Sure, if you are looking at one item at a time, you can easily use `is` or `as` operators.  If you are looking at multiple items, the linq methods `.OfType<T>()` and `.Cast<T>()` can come in handy.  I would still recommend using an interface or base class when appropriate.

Comment: Edited your question for clarity.  Really, this is a c#/linq question, and is about *hetero*geneous results.